# Remove "TRIM" in a column field?

Tags: trim

Referring to the question above, I have a problem when I'm trying to display my database in datagridview. I have a field "Items" but when I call it to the grid, the field will be name "TRIM(Items)". The "TRIM" comes from my sql statement :-

> > SELECT TRIM(Items) FROM others2

I need the TRIM so that there is no space when I called my data to the grid.
Anyway, how to remove the word but still it will trim my data?

Answer (score 0):

Try `SELECT TRIM(Items) As Items FROM others2`.